# How can I prevent elements with a transforming transition from resizing?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-transforms

I'm running into this issue where some (not all) elements, to which I have applied a 150ms transition duration as well as a translateY (transform) on hover, seemingly change size when the transform takes effect.

[image: moving-pixels.gif]

Has anyone experienced this as well, and if so, does anyone have a solution to this?

P.s. if you'd like to see these buttons for yourself they are live on https://www.kubbur.com/.

Comment: As you can see the size change is very brief but visible enough to be annoying.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and put just enough code into to your question so we can see the problem for ourselves. (I did try your site and there is no change of size for me - what browser/system are you on? I was using Edge/Windows10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted by DvdRom [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71373745/11376421) to this question, this behaviour is caused by the browser rendering the button with a subpixel width. During the transition the width is rounded down from e.g. 148.92px, causing the annoying behaviour. The solution I found to this problem - without setting an explicit width - is to apply a small transform on the horizontal axis:

```
.fix-vertical-subpixel-transition {
    transform: translateX(1px);
}
```

I won't claim to know why this worked (or whether it will in 100% of cases) but the limited testing I did showed positive results.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused the width of the button is actually `148.92px` and is rounded down to the nearest whole number when static and up while transitioning.

The only ways i can think of to fix this are using a different method than `translate` or use a fixed width.